# Optimize HTML reflow when typing in large contenteditable

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a large text editor application in Chromium.  The editable content resides in a contenteditable div.  This div can contain divs and spans which get various classes applied to them to create rich content.  The trouble I have is with a very large amount of text/html in my contenteditable div, typing is very slow since it causes the entire document to reflow (all of my div/spans inside of my contenteditable are position:relative).  If I make these position:absolute, typing is fine since reflow does not occur, but each child div/span overlaps.

Does anyone have a method for preserving the non-overlapping flow of position:relative, but without having to reflow the ENTIRE document when I type some text, even if it doesn't change line geometry?

-- Edit --

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/05xfc6pj/

CSS

```
.editable {
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

(Note, if the example isn't slow for you, copy and paste everything inside of .editable a few times)

I am using backbone.js to render these .wrapper items; would it be feasible making .wrapper have position:absolute and then calculating the position with JS (we know the height of each div), and setting a top offset?

Comment: `overflow:scroll` on the editable div?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and it doesn't help.  I need my typing to not have to cause a reflow on every keydown event, especially when typing in a single line and not changing the geometry of the divs.

Comment: You need to post some code if you want concrete answers/solutions. Otherwise, we are going to be just guessing at what your code does and how to solve it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion.  I've added some example code that highlights the problem.

Comment: Does removing `position: relative` from `.wrapper` work for you? - if you use relative, the browser needs to re-calculate the position for all other DOM elements (and they are all relative) so it takes time.

Comment: If I remove `position:relative` then it is still slow.  `position:absolute` is fine but all the divs are obviously overlapping each other.

Comment: can you move the `contenteditable="true"` attribute to each `.wrapper` then?  See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/05xfc6pj/3/

Comment: That is a good suggestion and works well in the fiddle; but I need the ability to select between `.wrapper` elements (like mouse selecting in Word).